# CSS: Placing text behind text

Tags: css, position, z-index

Inspired by: **view-source:https://vsociety.net/** I wanted to place and instance of text behind another instance of text, using z-index.
Apparently I cannot use z-index without also using the position attribute.
This is my code:

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center; letter-spacing: 4px; position: relative; z-index: 999">h

  <span style="color: #ccc; position: relative; z-index: -1; font-size: 70px;">e</span> llo

</h1>
```

This code does not work. I have searched using search engines and have asked ChatGPT3, but did not prevail in finding an answer for my specific question; all I found were instances of "image behind text."

I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

I have tried using z-index to position text behind text so that the "e" in *hello*, while making it appear bigger, would be placed behind the rest of "hello." It was my intention that "h - llo" would overlap the much larger "e" as a form of design. I have used `position: relative;`in conjunction with `z-index: -1;` This did not place the "e" behind "h - llo." I have also tried `position: absolute;` with similar results. The `<h1> contains the whole word and was originally given` z-index: 999; ``` and the *span* containing the letter e was given ``z-index: -1; ``` For a moment I thought this might be a matter of arithmetic, for +999 + -1 = +998, which does not yield a negative "layer position" for the span tag. However, giving the h1 tag a z-index of 1 and the span tag a z-index of -2 did not solve the problem.
The span tag contains the *e* and is nested within the h1 tag, which contains the entire word *hello*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.all-text {
  position: relative;
}

.text-hllo {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text-e {
  position: absolute;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-83%, -60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="all-text">
  <div class="text-hllo">h llo</div>
  <div class="text-e">e</div>
</div>
```